# Conflict with VS project dependencies and lib files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a big VS2008 solution containing >30 VS projects with legacy code. One of these projects (let's call it A) generates a header file, which is needed by a few other projects (for example B). When I go to "Project Dependencies" of the VS solution, I can check project A for project B's dependencies - but VS includes in the project B's linker command line options an additional argument for project A's lib ("A.lib"). Unfortunately, since project A does not create a lib file, this project B will never find one and cannot be built.

Is there a feasible solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `Ignore Import Library` in project A.

This option specifies that the (import) library generated by this configuration should not be imported into the dependent projects.